# Spring Rest Dropping Data When Returning

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a simple Spring Rest service setup to handle some JSON objects I have in a DB.  I have two applications; one looking to hold that data, and the other is looking to request/store that data locally to its DB.  The object used is in a shared Jar that both applications have access to, so they know the structure, expectations, etc.

When I run a request for the data I can see it coming in, but some of the data has been nulled out in the JSON.  I have setup breakpoints at the last return point for the source system, and when the data is there (pulled from DB) and ready to return it is intact.  Once it gets across the wire in any form via Postman or my 2nd App, some of the fields have been blanked out.

EDIT: Some code posted with specific names simplified for ease of reading

```
//------------------The Data "Source"------------------------------
//The source service that serves the content
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = { "/json/listObjectA" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<ObjectA> listAllObjectA() {
    List<ObjectA> allObjectA = ObjectA
            .getAll(thisApplicationContext);
    return allObjectA; //a breakpoint here shows the data as expected
    //the data in the DB is correct in source, confirmed.
}


//------------------The Requesting "Target"-----------------------------
//trying to get that data, setting up a baseURL for the service works
//when using this block of code with debuggers on, it reaches the source above.
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<ObjectA[]> sfResponse = rest.getForEntity(
coreBaseLocation+"json/listObjectA",
                ObjectA[].class);
ObjectA[] sfList = sfResponse.getBody();
// right here debugging, the list has the correct number, but some of the data is missing
for (ObjectA sf: sfList) {
    sf.setId(null); //clear the local id, a uuid is persisting
    sf.save(thisApplicationContext);
}

//------------------The data class------------------------------
@Entity
public class ObjectA{
...
protected String ObjectBUuid;
protected String ObjectCUuid;
...
// basic POJO getters/setters/constructor etc. nothing fancy
```

Also for reference, `ObjectA` is a simple "Join" object between an `ObjectB` and `ObjectC`.  A simple join table doesn't work since I am storing a lot more meta data about the association that isn't super relevant to this but needed for business reasons.

```
//Here is a copy of the "response" from Postman hitting that json url.
//again, in debug before this is sent back the data looks correct with the Uuids populated (like in the DB)
[
{
  "id": 1, //local id of the ObjectA
  "uuid": "1464d8dc-0281-4850-a51d-a375f7a2fd04",  //ObjectA's uuid
  ... metadata stuff ...
  // end of obj., no reference to the ObjectB/C uuids at all in the returned obj.
}, // more data here matching the number I expect from the DB and the source debug breakpoint, just with the reference uuid missing.
```

Comment: We'll need a lot more than this if you would like real help. How about some code? Can you show us the DTOs and the controller? And, are you sure the values aren't null and simply being left out because of that?

Comment: @EngineerDollery updated with a lot of code blocks showing what I am working with.  Let me know if it is unclear or anything is missing.

Comment: NOTE: I also included a "response" from Postman, which is showing the data but not showing any reference to the missing fields.